# File path in scheme/racket/

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, filepath

```
(define-struct directory (name contents))
;A directory is a (make-directory String (list-of files)
;A file is one of:
; a * String (containing the name of the file; non-empty and does not contain
"/"
;* a Directory
```

What I am trying to make is a function that consumes a directory and a file name as a string. Then the function should produces the file path with each file or directory separated by "/".

A sample directory:

```
(define a1 (make-directory "a1" (list "a1.pdf" "a1q1.rkt" "a1q2.rkt" "a1q3.rkt")))
(define a2 (make-directory "a2" (list "a2.pdf")))
(define assns (make-directory "assns" (list a1 a2)))
(define labs (make-directory "labs" (list "lab01.pdf" "lab02.pdf")))
(define final (make-directory "final" empty))
(define cs115 (make-directory "cs115" (list assns labs final "style.pdf" "survivial.pdf")))
```

for example

```
(path cs115 "a2.pdf")
```

should produce

```
"cs115/assns/a2/a2.pdf"
```

What I have so far:

```
(define (find dir name)
  (cond 
    [(string=? (directory-name dir) name) name]
    [(member? name (directory-contents dir))
     (string-append (directory-name dir) "/" name)]
    [(cons? (directory-contents dir))
     (content-list (directory-name dir)(directory-contents dir) name)]
    ))


(define (content-list dir-name dir-list name)
  (cond
    [(empty?  dir-list)
             (content-list dir-name (rest dir-list) name)]
    [(equal? (first dir-list) name)
     (string-append dir-name "/" (first dir-list))]
    [(directory? (first dir-list))
     (find (first dir-list) name)]
    [else (content-list dir-name (rest dir-list) name)]
    ))
```

Regards,
Sam

Comment: Although I'm not sure I understand your question, the function you want _sounds_ like Racket's [build-path](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Manipulating_Paths.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._build-path%29%29)? Also keep in mind `apply` and `list*`.

Comment: My question is simply how to create a file path from the directory created above in the question

Comment: I see, so the function should find file(s) with the desired name, at any depth in the tree of directories, and return the full path to it/them. If there's more than one such file, does it need to return only the first it happens to find, or all of them? Also: What code have you tried so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: There is no possibility that more than file have the same name.

Comment: There is no possibility that more than file would have the same name. Unfortunately, we have to use beginning student with list abbreviations as our racket language so we can't use loops. My plan is to have a function that consumes a directory and passes the list of that directory to function that consumes a list and checks if that file is there. I will add what I have so far above in the question

Comment: Now you mention BSL.

Comment: Sorry I forgot my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

This finds *a* file of the desired name, passing a test using the example you supplied.

```
#lang racket/base

(require racket/match
         racket/string
         rackunit)

(struct directory (name       ;string?
                   contents)) ;(listof (or/c string? directory?))

(define a1 (directory "a1" (list "a1.pdf" "a1q1.rkt" "a1q2.rkt" "a1q3.rkt")))
(define a2 (directory "a2" (list "a2.pdf")))
(define assns (directory "assns" (list a1 a2)))
(define labs (directory "labs" (list "lab01.pdf" "lab02.pdf")))
(define final (directory "final" '()))
(define cs115 (directory "cs115" (list assns labs final "style.pdf" "survivial.pdf")))

;; path-to : directory? string? -> (or/c string? #f)
(define (path-to dir desired-filename)
  (let loop ([dirnames (list (directory-name dir))]
             [contents (directory-contents dir)])
    (for/or ([x (in-list contents)])
      (match x
        [(directory dirname contents)   (loop (cons dirname dirnames) contents)]
        [(and fn (== desired-filename)) (string-join (reverse (cons fn dirnames)) "/")]
        [_                              #f]))))

(check-equal? (path-to cs115 "a2.pdf")
              "cs115/assns/a2/a2.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer I came up with however, I was informed that my code is not that efficient.

```
;;------------------
;;Defined Structures
;;------------------

(define-struct directory (name contents))
;; A Directory is a (make-directory Str (listof File))


;; A File is one of: 
;; * a Str (containing the name of the file; nonempty and does not contain "/")
;; * a Directory


;;-----------------
;;Defined Variables
;;-----------------

(define a1 (make-directory "a1" (list "a1.pdf" "a1q1.rkt"
                                      "a1q2.rkt" "a1q3.rkt")))
(define a2 (make-directory "a2" (list "a2.pdf")))
(define assns (make-directory "assns" (list a1 a2)))
(define labs (make-directory "labs" (list "lab01.pdf" "lab02.pdf")))
(define final (make-directory "final" empty))
(define cs115 (make-directory "cs115" (list assns labs final 
                                            "style.pdf" "survival.pdf")))

;;--------------------
;;Helper Function # 1
;;---------------------

;;(search-dirlist list name)

;;-------
;;Purpose
;;-------

;;(search-dirlist list name):This function consumes a directroy list 
;;                           and searches name (the other consumed
;;                           variable) in that list and produces that 
;;                           path


;;--------
;;Contract
;;--------

;;(search-dirlist list name): (listof Files) Str -> Str



;;--------
;;Example
;;--------


(check-expect (search-dirlist (list assns labs final 
                                    "style.pdf" "survival.pdf") "survival.pdf")
              "survival.pdf")
(check-expect (search-dirlist (list assns labs final 
                                    "style.pdf" "survival.pdf") "survival.pdf") 
              "survival.pdf")
(check-expect (search-dirlist (list assns labs final 
                                    "style.pdf" "survival.pdf") "lab01.pdf")
              "labs/lab01.pdf")
(check-expect (search-dirlist (list "a1.pdf" "a1q1.rkt" "a1q2.rkt" "a1q3.pdf") "a1q2.rkt")
              "a1q2.rkt")



;;--------------------
;;Function Head & Body
;;--------------------

(define (search-dirlist dirlist name)
  (cond 
    [(empty? dirlist) ""]
    [else
     (cond 
       [(and (directory? (first dirlist)) 
             (contain-file (first dirlist) name)) 
        (string-append (directory-name (first dirlist)) 
                       (cond 
                         [(string=? name 
                                    (directory-name 
                                     (first dirlist))) ""]
                         [else "/"])
                       (search-dirlist (directory-contents (first dirlist)) name))]
       [(and (string? (first dirlist))
             (string=? (first dirlist) name)) (first dirlist)]
       [else (search-dirlist (rest dirlist) name)])]))


;;-----
;;Tests
;;-----


(check-expect (search-dirlist (list assns labs final 
                               "style.pdf" "survival.pdf") "style.pdf")
              "style.pdf")
(check-expect (search-dirlist (list assns labs final 
                               "style.pdf" "survival.pdf") "a2")
              "assns/a2")
(check-expect (search-dirlist (list assns labs final 
                               "style.pdf" "survival.pdf") "a1q3.rkt")
              "assns/a1/a1q3.rkt")
(check-expect (search-dirlist (list assns labs final 
                               "style.pdf" "survival.pdf") "labs")
              "labs")
(check-expect (search-dirlist (list assns labs final 
                               "style.pdf" "survival.pdf") "final")
              "final")
(check-expect (search-dirlist (list a1 a2) "a2")
              "a2")
(check-expect (search-dirlist (list a1 a2) "a1.pdf")
              "a1/a1.pdf")
(check-expect (search-dirlist (list assns labs final 
                               "style.pdf" "survival.pdf") "lab01.pdf")
              "labs/lab01.pdf")
(check-expect (search-dirlist (list assns labs final 
                               "style.pdf" "survival.pdf") "lab02.pdf")
              "labs/lab02.pdf")







;;--------------------
;;Helper Function # 2
;;---------------------

;;(contain-file dir name)

;;-------
;;Purpose
;;-------

;;(contain-file dir name):Consumes a directory "dir" and name
;;                        Check if the name exists in the
;;                        directroy and produces boolean
;;                        accordingly.


;;--------
;;Contract
;;--------

;;(contain-file dir name): Directory Str -> Boolean

;;--------
;;Example
;;--------


(check-expect (contain-file cs115 "style.pdf") true)
(check-expect (contain-file assns "assns") true)
(check-expect (contain-file cs115 "lab02.pdf") true)
(check-expect (contain-file labs "a1q1.rkt") false)


;;--------------------
;;Function Head & Body
;;--------------------

(define (contain-file dir name)
  (cond 
    [(string=? (directory-name dir) name) true]
    [(list-contains-file (directory-contents dir) name) true]
    [else false]))



;;-----
;;Tests
;;-----


(check-expect (contain-file labs "labs") 
              true)
(check-expect (contain-file labs "lab01.pdf") 
              true)
(check-expect (contain-file labs "style.pdf") 
              false)
(check-expect (contain-file final "final") 
              true)
(check-expect (contain-file final "a1") 
              false)
(check-expect (contain-file cs115 "cs115") 
              true)
(check-expect (contain-file cs115 "assns") 
              true)
(check-expect (contain-file assns "a2") 
              true)
(check-expect (contain-file assns "a1q3.rkt") 
              true)
(check-expect (contain-file assns "a2.pdf") 
              true)
(check-expect (contain-file assns "labs") 
              false)
(check-expect (contain-file cs115 "labs") 
              true)
(check-expect (contain-file cs115 "final") 
              true)
(check-expect (contain-file cs115 "style.pdf") 
              true)
(check-expect (contain-file cs115 "survival.pdf")
              true)
(check-expect (contain-file cs115 "random-file") 
              false)





;;--------------------
;;Helper Function # 3
;;---------------------

;;(list-contain-file dirlist name)

;;-------
;;Purpose
;;-------

;;(list-contains-file dirlist name):


;;--------
;;Contract
;;--------

;;(list-contains-file dirlist name):

;;--------
;;Example
;;--------

(check-expect (list-contains-file empty "survival.pdf") false);base case
(check-expect (list-contains-file (list "a1.pdf" "a1q1.rkt" "a1q2.rkt" "a1q3.rkt") 
                                  "a1q2.rkt") true);simple case
(check-expect (list-contains-file  (list assns labs final "style.pdf" "survival.pdf")
                                   "labs")true);check in a structure(directory name)
(check-expect (list-contains-file  (list a1 a2 labs final) 
                                   "lab01.pdf") true);check in a structure(directory contents)



;;--------------------
;;Function Head & Body
;;--------------------

(define (list-contains-file dirlist name)
  (cond 
    [(empty? dirlist) false]
    [(string? (first dirlist))
     (cond
       [(string=? (first dirlist) name) true] 
       [else  (list-contains-file (rest dirlist) name)])]
    [(directory? (first dirlist))
     (cond 
       [(string=? (directory-name (first dirlist)) name) true]
       [(list-contains-file (directory-contents (first dirlist)) name) true]
       [else (list-contains-file (rest dirlist) name)])]))


;;-----
;;Tests
;;-----

(check-expect (list-contains-file  (list assns labs final
                                     "style.pdf" "survival.pdf")
                               "assns") true)
(check-expect (list-contains-file  (list assns labs final
                                     "style.pdf" "survival.pdf")
                               "a1") true)
(check-expect (list-contains-file  (list assns labs final
                                     "style.pdf" "survival.pdf") 
                               "a1q1.rkt")true)
(check-expect (list-contains-file  (list assns labs final
                                     "style.pdf" "survival.pdf") 
                               "labs") true)

(check-expect (list-contains-file  (list assns labs final
                                     "style.pdf" "survival.pdf") 
                               "xyz") false)
(check-expect (list-contains-file  (list a1 a2) "a1.pdf") true)
(check-expect (list-contains-file (list "a1.pdf" "a1q1.rkt"
                                    "a1q2.rkt" "a1q3.rkt") 
                              "a1q2.rkt") true)
(check-expect (list-contains-file (list "lab01.pdf" "lab02.pdf") 
                              "lab02.pdf") true)


;;---------------
;;Main Function
;;---------------

;;(find dir name)

;;-------
;;Purpose
;;-------

;;(find dir name):This function consume a directroy dir and
;;                a Str name and identifies wheather name is
;;                is in a sub-directory of file and produces 
;;                the path to the file/subdirectroy, if the 
;;                doesn't exist produce false.



;;--------
;;Contract
;;--------

;;(find dir name) Directory Str -> (Anyof False or Str)



;;--------
;;Example
;;--------

(check-expect (find cs115 "cs115") "cs115")
(check-expect (find cs115 "final") "cs115/final")
(check-expect (find cs115 "survival.pdf") "cs115/survival.pdf")
(check-expect (find cs115 "lab01.pdf") "cs115/labs/lab01.pdf")
(check-expect (find assns "a1q3.rkt") "assns/a1/a1q3.rkt")
(check-expect (find labs "a1") false)

;;--------------------
;;Function Head & Body
;;--------------------

(define (find dir name)
  (cond 
    [(contain-file dir name) (cond
                            [(string=? (directory-name dir) name) 
                             (directory-name dir)]
                            [else (string-append 
                                   (directory-name dir) "/"
                                   (search-dirlist (directory-contents dir) name))])]
    [else false]))


;;-----
;;Tests
;;-----



(check-expect (find cs115 "assns") "cs115/assns")
(check-expect (find cs115 "labs") "cs115/labs")
(check-expect (find cs115 "final") "cs115/final")
(check-expect (find cs115 "style.pdf") "cs115/style.pdf")
(check-expect (find cs115 "survival.pdf") "cs115/survival.pdf")
(check-expect (find cs115 "a1") "cs115/assns/a1")
(check-expect (find cs115 "a2") "cs115/assns/a2")
(check-expect (find final "a1.pdf") false)
(check-expect (find a1 "a2") false)
(check-expect (find a2 "a1q2.rkt") false)
(check-expect (find cs115 "random-file") false)
(check-expect (find cs115 "a2.pdf") "cs115/assns/a2/a2.pdf")
(check-expect (find cs115 "a1q2.rkt") "cs115/assns/a1/a1q2.rkt")
(check-expect (find cs115 "lab01.pdf") "cs115/labs/lab01.pdf")
(check-expect (find assns "assns") "assns")
(check-expect (find final "final") "final")
```